# Printing with tab separation instead of spaces

Tags: python, printing, tabs

Say I want to print like this:

```
print 1,"hello", 2, "fart"
```

but with tabs instead of spaces, what is the most pythonic way of doing this, in python 2?

It's a really silly question but I couldn't seem to find an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach is to **look towards the future!**

```
# Available since Python 2.6
from __future__ import print_function

# Now you can use Python 3's print
print(1, 'hello', 2, 'fart', sep='\t')
```

Comment: In most cases this is probably the better approach. The reason i won't delete my answer is because this ``__future__`` import is not available in all Python 2 versions.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: Indeed, if I am not mistaken, it's only available since Python 2.6

Answer (score 3):

Using `str.join`:

```
print '\t'.join(map(str, (1, "hello", 2, "fart")))
```

Comment: I tried that! I get: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#148>", line 1, in <module>
    print '\t'.join((1, "hello", 2, "fart"))d
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found`

Comment: Sorry, i completely overlooked that. With my code above, every argument needs to be a string. I updated my code to cast everything to a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a generator expression like

```
print '\t'.join((str(i) for i in (1, "hello", 2, "fart")))
```